# Firestore batch create recurring calendar events

Tags: angular, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Flutter app and an Angular Admin Dashboard accessing the same Firebase project.

I need to create a recurring Calendar Event in Angular and show it in Flutter as documents.

I already have a simple system with identical fields in both the Admin dashboard and flutter app. The Admins, to avoid repetition, want to be able to create recurring events (e.g. A club meeting held on the third Thursday monthly).

Can anyone point me on the right direction please?

Comment: since you use firebase you could use the  schedule functions. you will have to change your account to to blaze to use it though. Make sure you dont run it too often. But essentially you could create a document that is has to pass through and create reoccurring events. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Comment: Thanks Henrik. Already on Blaze and the scheduler is not really what I'm after. I use the scheduler for other functionality in the app.

I need to create recurring evens in firestore so other users can access them.